# How do I get Rails to work with a newer version of Ruby on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I installed [Ruby 2.3.1](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), then I installed [Ruby on Rails](http://railsinstaller.org/en).

The Rails install gives me an older version ruby.exe (2.2.4).

The Rails installer also added the older version of Ruby to the head of my PATH:

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin;C:**\Ruby23-x64\bin**;...

so checking `ruby -v` I get 2.2.4.

I modified the PATH precedence:

C:**\Ruby23-x64\bin**;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin;...

..and `ruby -v` does indeed report 2.3.1)

When I cd into a Rails project and `rails s` the message tells me I am using 2.2.4 (and as well that I should be using 2.2.5 or **2.3.1**. This whether I modify PATH to give 2.2.4 or 2.3.1 precedence...)

I understand rvm and rbenv don't work on windows and [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/downloads) is no longer supported...
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe
C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\ruby.exe

How do I get Rails to work with the newer version of Ruby?

Comment: Next up, "[chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org)"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://chocolatey.org works. There's some buggery involved with compiling nokogiri to work, but otherwise chocolatey addresses my question adequately. See [Richard Pecks excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33593870/5225057) for information on how to successfully compile nokogiri.